# Enzyme Find By className and Simulate Click

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

In enzyme, simulating a click on an item found by className does not seem to work. The issue is that the mockFn is not mocking `toggleSort`. But in other cases mocking a function this way works perfectly. Why the inconsistencies in the way enzyme handle mocking class functions? All of the below cases for testing the event handler toggleSort does not work.

```
import React from "react";

export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  toggleSort = e => {
    console.log(e, "dd");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <button type="button" className="button" onClick={this.toggleSort} />
    );
  }
}
```

The test:

```
import React from "react";

import Enzyme, { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

import Hello from "./Hello";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("Hello", () => {
  it("should do the right thing", async () => {
    const mockFn = jest.fn();
    const component = shallow(<Hello />);

    component.instance().toggleSort = mockFn;

    await component
      .find(".button")
      .at(0)
      .simulate("click");

    expect(mockFn).toBeCalled();
  });

  it("should work with spy", () => {
     const component = shallow(<Hello />);
     const spy = jest.spyOn(component.instance(), "toggleSort");
     component.update();
     component
       .find(".button")
       .at(0)
       .simulate("click");
     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });

   it("should work with prototype", () => {
    const mockFn = jest.fn()
    Hello.prototype.toggleSort = mockFn
    const component = shallow(<Hello />);
    component
      .find(".button")
      .at(0)
      .simulate("click");
    expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Below is the test file on codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/n0jv07kqll

Comment: Try the following:
`
const spy = jest.spyOn(component.instance(), 'toggleSort');
component.update();
component.find('.button').at(0).simulate('click');

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
`

Comment: @Chris that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

`toggleSort` is an instance property so you'll have to mock using the instance since it doesn't exist on the class prototype.

`onClick` is bound directly to `this.toggleSort` so you'll either have to force a re-render so it gets re-bound to your spy:

```
it("should work with spy", () => {
  const component = shallow(<Hello />);
  const spy = jest.spyOn(component.instance(), "toggleSort");
  component.setState({});  // <= force re-render (sometimes component.update() isn't enough)
  component
    .find(".button")
    .at(0)
    .simulate("click");
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
});
```

...or call it using an arrow function so the current value of `this.toggleSort` gets called:

```
<button type="button" className="button" onClick={() => this.toggleSort()} />
```

...which can then be tested like this:

```
it("should work with spy", () => {
  const component = shallow(<Hello />);
  const spy = jest.spyOn(component.instance(), "toggleSort");
  component
    .find(".button")
    .at(0)
    .simulate("click");
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
});
```